# Enhancements in type- and property-perfecting sports

Tags: philosophy-of-technology

Roduit et. al. [1] talk about property- and type-perfecting driving forces in sports. Many sports such as most (all?) olympic sports are by most people considered to be type-perfecting i.e. they look for the fastest, strongest, ... *human* (Citius, Altius, Fortius). As such, the authors conclude, there should be limits imposed on what enhancements may be used in such sport, depending on what it means to be (remain) human.

What are some examples of sports that are considered to be property-perfecting, i.e. enhancements are employed regardless of how human the participant remains?

Is Formula 1 [2] such a sport? Most enhancements are made to the vehicle of the *human* (?) driver. Is it relevant in this sport that the drivers are human?

[1] Johann A. R. Roduit & Roman Gaehwiler (2018) Ethics and enhancement in sport: becoming the fastest (human?) being, Sport in Society, 21:4, 713-719

[2] https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formula_One

Comment: I am unclear what you mean by "Formula 1". Is that a kind of car? Regardless, welcome to this SE!

Comment: Formula 1 is a single-seater auto racing sport. Edited in a wiki link.

Comment: afaict so called "trans" humanists have no concern for humans, humanity, or humanism

Comment: Actually formula 1 does constantly change to remain a human sport. At one point for example massively reducing engine capacity to prevent deaths caused by exceeding human capability.. or insisting upon safety features which limit car efficiency. We could produce driverless vehicles hitting far greater speeds and g-forces than are possible with human drivers. F1 drivers are usually as fit as any athlete though. Piloting an F1 car around Monaco is not something an ordinary person could do.

Comment: Something like Combat Robotics (Robot Wars/Battlebots) might be an interesting one to consider.  i.e. where the human is not really the 'competitor' at all.